# Churn rate prediction based on sequence data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, pytorch

I am trying to build a machine learning model that can predict if a certain user will churn based on its historical static and dynamic data. The data looks like below:

```
1) timestamp, user1, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 0
2) timestamp, user1, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 0
3) timestamp, user1, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 1

4) timestamp, user2, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 0
5) timestamp, user2, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 0
6) timestamp, user2, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 0
7) timestamp, user2, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 0
8) timestamp, user2, user info (static), event info(dynamic), 0
```

There are many `user_id` in the dataset and each could be a varied-length sequence. The features for each user are two parts. One is `user info`, which can be regarded as constant for each user. The other part is the `event info`, which includes features that change over time.

Please let me know what should be my approach to handle such a problem either in machine learning/deep learning, it is better to have a detailed step by step tutorial in `pytorch`.

Answer (score 0):

"user_id" is divided into two parts "user_info" and "event_info" where "user_info" is constant part so we need not to worry about it and "event_info" is dynamic in nature which include features which sometimes contain null/NA values and other time have legit values.

Because we don't know the nature of features, we're taking both cases continuous and categorical.

Cases:

- If dynamic features are **continuous values**-

  - you can opt for zero, -1 or any other integer (depends upon the present values of feature(s))  whenever you find null/NA value in the features - by this your model(ML or DL) will able to work efficiently with the dynamic features.
- Second case when its **categorical values**-

  - For this just include one more category in each feature(s) which represents, may be the Null/NA value.

That's how i handled this situation back and it worked pretty well. and for this you don't need any pytorch tutorial, python will do the work.